# How can i call two controllers on one div?

Tags: angularjs

HI I need call two controllers from same div i.e div id="div1" cntr1 and cntr2,Is it possible to do?

```
<div id="div1" ng-controller="ctrl1">
</div>
```

Please help me out ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nested controller - you can access ctrl1's field and function in ctrl2 also .You can use $parent.

---

```js
<div ng-controller="ctrl1">
     <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a directive that has the desired controller:

```
angular.module(...).directive('ctrl2', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        controller: 'ctrl2'
    };
});
```

Use as:

```
<div id="div1" ng-controller="ctrl1" ctrl2></div>
```